# React js callback functions

Tags: reactjs, callback

I have a function A that is called on clicking a number. The function A sets the state of a variable and calls another function B as a callback. B now has to make a redux call to get data from an API after which another function C is called which generates a pdf with the data obtained from the API.

The problem I am facing is in function B where it fetches the data from the API correctly but I am not able to pass the data to the next function C.

Please help

```
    functionA = (record) =>
    {
        this.setState(
            {pdfInvoiceNum: record.no}, ()=>{
              this.functionB(record)
            });
    };

    functionB = (record) => 
    {
      this.props.getDetailForPdf(this.state.pdfInvoiceNum)  //=>This sets purchasedetail
      this.functionC(this.props.purchasedetail)           
    }

    functionC = (record) =>
    {
       console.log(record)     //Doesn't print anything when I click the first time but prints correct data when I click second time
    }


    //Click starts here
    <a onClick={()=>{this.functionA(record)}}>{text}</a>
```

Here are the calls:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
getPurchaseDetailPdf : (pdfInvoiceNum) => dispatch(fetchPurchaseDetailPdf(pdfInvoiceNum)),
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
purchasedetailpdf: state.purchasesReducer.purchasedetailpdf}
};
```

purchasesAction.js

```
export const fetchPurchaseDetailPdf = (number) =>  {
            console.log("PO is:"+ PONumber)
                return (dispatch) => {
                    dispatch({type: FETCH_START});
                    var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
                    
                    axios.get(`${apiUrl}.../${number}`,
              ).then(({data}) => {
                          const results = data.map((row, index) => ({
                            key: index,
                            name : row.name,   
                          }))
                          dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS});
                          dispatch({type: PURCHASEDETAILPDF_DATA, payload: results});
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                      dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message});
                      console.log("Error****:", error.message);
                    });
                  }
                }
```

PurchasesReducer.js

```
import {FETCH_START, FETCH_SUCCESS, FETCH_ERROR, PURCHASEDETAILPDF_DATA} from '../../constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = {
    pending: false,
    purchasedetailpdf: [],
    error: null
}

export default function purchaseReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_START: 
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: true
            }
        case FETCH_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                contracts: action.payload
            }
        case FETCH_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                error: action.error
            }
        case PURCHASEDETAILPDF_DATA: 
            return {
                ...state,
                purchasedetailpdf: action.payload,
            }

        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

export const getPurchaseDetailPdf = state => state.purchasedetailpdf;
export const getPurchaseDetailPdfPending = state => state.pending;
export const getPurchaseDetailPdfError = state => state.error;
```

Comment: Is `this.props.getDetailForPdf()` an `async` function?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros This is the way it is written:

```

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   getPurchaseDetailPdf : (pdfInvoiceNum) => dispatch(fetchPurchaseDetailPdf(pdfInvoiceNum)),
});


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
purchasedetailpdf: state.purchasesReducer.purchasedetailpdf}
};

```

API call is here:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways

1. use async/await

first let your action return a promise

```js
export const fetchPurchaseDetailPdf = (number) =>  {
  console.log("PO is:"+ PONumber)
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_START});
    var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
                    
    return axios.get(`${apiUrl}.../${number}`)
      .then(({data}) => {
        const results = data.map((row, index) => ({
          key: index,
          name : row.name,   
        }))
        dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS});
        dispatch({type: PURCHASEDETAILPDF_DATA, payload: results});

        return results;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message});
        console.log("Error****:", error.message);
      });
  }
}
```

and then you can get result from functionB and pass it into functionC

```js
functionB = async (record) => {
  const result = await this.props.getDetailForPdf(this.state.pdfInvoiceNum)  //=>This sets purchasedetail
  this.functionC(result)
}

functionC = (record) => {
   console.log(record)     //Doesn't print anything when I click the first time but prints correct data when I click second time
}
```

2. use a onCompleted function callback (I prefer this)

pass functionC into functionB as a callback, and it will be executed while api call completed

```js
functionB =(record) => {
  const result = this.props.getDetailForPdf({
    number: this.state.pdfInvoiceNum,
    onCompleted: this.functionC
  })
}

functionC = (record) => {
   console.log(record)     //Doesn't print anything when I click the first time but prints correct data when I click second time
}
```

modify your action to accept onCompleted callback function:

```js
export const fetchPurchaseDetailPdf = ({ number, onCompleted }) =>  {
  console.log("PO is:"+ PONumber)
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_START});
    var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
                    
    axios.get(`${apiUrl}.../${number}`)
      .then(({data}) => {
        const results = data.map((row, index) => ({
          key: index,
          name : row.name,   
        }))
        dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS});
        dispatch({type: PURCHASEDETAILPDF_DATA, payload: results});

        if (onCompleted) {
          onCompleted(results)
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message});
        console.log("Error****:", error.message);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @chonnychu . I tried both methods and the first solution solved the issue. Thanks again!